# Pyaudio setting output = to variable

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, pyaudio

How could you set a variable equal to 'O' or '-' and then put that in an if statement like the one below:

```
if variable == 'O':
    print 'hi'
```

how could you do that for:

```
import threading
from array import array
from Queue import Queue, Full
import pyaudio


CHUNK_SIZE = 1024
MIN_VOLUME = 500
BUF_MAX_SIZE = CHUNK_SIZE * 10


def main():
    stopped = threading.Event()
    q = Queue(maxsize=int(round(BUF_MAX_SIZE / CHUNK_SIZE)))

    listen_t = threading.Thread(target=listen, args=(stopped, q))
    listen_t.start()
    record_t = threading.Thread(target=record, args=(stopped, q))
    record_t.start()

    try:
        while True:
        listen_t.join(0.1)
        record_t.join(0.1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        stopped.set()

    listen_t.join()
    record_t.join()


def record(stopped, q):
    while True:
        if stopped.wait(timeout=0):
            break
        chunk = q.get()
        vol = max(chunk)
        if vol >= MIN_VOLUME:
        # TODO: write to file
            print "O",
        else:
            print "-",


def listen(stopped, q):
    stream = pyaudio.PyAudio().open(
        format=pyaudio.paInt16,
        channels=2,
        rate=44100,
        input=True,
        frames_per_buffer=1024,
    )

    while True:
        if stopped.wait(timeout=0):
            break
        try:
            q.put(array('h', stream.read(CHUNK_SIZE)))
        except Full:
            pass  # discard


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Could you use that so if the output is 'O' then print hi?  Will somebody write the code for me because I have been trying for a little bit to write this code and I have still not been able to make the code work for me.  Thank You.

Comment: where you want to put these lines?

Answer (score 1):

In order to use if then statement in Python, first we need to declare variable value with proper syntax according to requirement and type.

```
s = "O"
if s == 'O':
    print 'hi'
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer

Comment: @Huangism Actually the question is very unclear, I don't know where he/she want to put these lines

Comment: Understandable, you should ask for clarification before posting 3 lines of code without any explanation

Comment: @Huangism FYI I already asked but it is not my concern, i just answered the desire question

Comment: To my initial comment, add some explanation as to what's going on in the code. The OP is obviously a beginner, your explanation will help OP and future readers. I only left the first comment because your answer has been flagged for low quality